# transition with -webkit- transform in shorthand rule

Tags: css, vendor-prefix, autoprefixer, postcss

I have grunt with postcss running autoprefixer, and the code:

```
transition: transform .3s, color .3s;
```

... is outputting:

```
transition: color .3s, -webkit-transform .3s;
transition: transform .3s, color .3s;
transition: transform .3s, color .3s, -webkit-transform .3s;
```

But shouldn't it be outputting this?

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s, color .3s;
transition: transform .3s, color .3s;
```

My postcss settings are:

```
postcss: {
    options: {
        map: {
            inline: false, // save all sourcemaps as separate files...
            annotation: '../css/' // ...to the specified directory
        },

        processors: [
            require('autoprefixer')({browsers: 'last 2 versions'}), // add vendor prefixes
        ]
    },
    dist: {
        src: '../css/*.css'
    }
}
```

I have no idea if I'm doing anything wrong, if it's outputting incorrectly, or if it's actually correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have write the correct css, its is not you fault, you can also check you css on their [official page](http://autoprefixer.github.io/), 
and according to your browser selection setting {browsers: 'last 2 versions'} you don't need any transition prefix for last 2 webkit versions, generated css is correct.